# Maven 'Missing artifact

Tags: maven

My local rpository is already has cxf-bundle-2.7.5.jar(download from search.maven.org by myself) and pom but eclipse still get a error 'Missing artifact org.apache.cxf:cxf-bundle:bundle:2.7.5' and when I update project repository make a file cxf-bundle-2.7.5.bundle.lastUpdated everytime. How could i  fix this problem and why.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <type>bundle</type>
    </dependency>
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: It might be that your eclipse is pointing at a different local repository. Check the maven settings in the eclipse preferences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple answer is that the bundle is not really a bundle in the meaning of the type. If you take a look at [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.cxf%7Ccxf-bundle%7C2.7.5%7Cbundle) you will see that there are jar, source, javadoc available so you need to change the dependency definition into the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```